# MySQL Join 3 relative tables in one statement

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables the main table is the `Student` Table which has the following columns:

```
ID
Name
School
GPA
Email
```

Then I have `SchoolData` which has the following Columns

```
ID
Name
Location
Colors
```

Finally I have `LocationData` with

```
ID
City
State
```

The tables are tied together using the ID columns

I am trying to accomplish something like:

```
select * FROM Players,LocationData,SchoolData WHERE 
Players.ID = "3" AND 
SchoolData.ID = Players.School
LocationData.ID = SchoolData.Location
```

If I provide the Students ID value I should be able to return their school and the school location. I do not use Foreign keys often but did set them up for this example. Do I use those or Join my tables?

Comment: You are using old notation instead of JOIN also you are missing AND for each condition.

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using joins, like this.

```
select * from players
join schooldata on players.school = schooldata.id
join locationdata on schooldata.location = locationdata.id
where players.id = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `Players` as your table you have `Student` so I think you meant `Student`

Try this :

```
SELECT * FROM Student 
JOIN SchoolData ON Student.school = SchoolData.id
JOIN LocationData ON SchoolData.location = LocationData.id
WHERE Student.id = 3
```